# Get membership user email if not null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

in my web site, mobile number is userId, then some people has email,and some others no, how can i check one user has email or not?

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
string userEmail = mu.Email.ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
{
  //do something
}
```

in above code i get error in 2nd line,any help?

Comment: mu is null or mu.Email is null. dont use mu.Email.ToString, use string.IsNullOrEmpty(mu.Email) instead

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. mu in not null, mu.email is null

Comment: @Thalmann in aspnet_membership user has a record, in email column is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Email string is null, then ToSting()ing it will throw an exception. You should remove that method call. It's probably you're main problem.

What is the error?

Try debugging like this

```
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
            throw new ArgumentException("username is null or whitespace");

    MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(username);
    if (mu == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Couldn't get a membership user for that username");
    string userEmail = mu.Email; // email is already a string, do not invoke Tostring() on it

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userEmail))
     {
         //do something
     }
```

Comment: The main of the answer is probably just removing the ToString() method call on mu.Email.